# better way to handle these arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have a menu with 3 groups of check boxes that will be used to filter items on a page. They are `store`, `city` and `level`. Checking any box in any of the groups add the value to the corresponding array in an object that looks like this:

```
items = {
  store: [],
  city: [],
  level: []
}
```

The default is for all items to be visible and no check boxes checked. When boxes are checked, only the items corresponding to

Each time a box is checked or unchecked, the items are filtered. First the items are filtered by `store` and `city` and then that sub-set of items is further filtered by `level`. If no `level` boxes are checked, all levels are displayed, but if any are checked, only checked `store/city`s of the checked `level`s are displayed.

So my object can look like this

```
itms = {
  store: [
    'north',
    'evans',
    'dodge'
  ],
  city: [
    'boston',
    'miami',
  ],
  level: [
    'gold',
    'silver'
  ]
}
```

In the end, I need a string that looks like this:
`.north.gold,.north.silver,.evans.gold,.evans.silver,.dodge.gold,.dodge.silver,.boston.gold,.boston.silver,.miami.gold,.miami.silver,` - *order doesn't matter*

If my object looked like this:

```
items = {
  store: [
    'north',
    'evans',
    'dodge'
  ],
  cite: [ 'miami' ],
  level: []
}
```

I'd need a string that looks like this:
`.north,.evans,.dodge,.miami`

Hopefully, you get the gist...

To derive the properly formatted string from the object, I'm doing some, what I'm pretty sure is horribly inefficient, iterating:

```
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {
        value.forEach(item => {
          if(key !== 'level') {
            finalSelectors.push(`.${item}`);
            if (key === 'city') {
              finalSelectors.push(`.${item}_child`);
            }
          }
        });
      }
      
      let selectorsArr = finalSelectors;
      const reFinalSelectors = [];
      const selectedLevels = items.level;
      if(selectedLevels.length) {
        if(items.city.length || items.location.length) {
          finalSelectors.forEach(selector => {
            selectedLevels.forEach(level => {
              reFinalSelectors.push(`.${level}${selector}`);
            });
          });
        } else {
          selectedLevels.forEach(level => {
            reFinalSelectors.push(`.${level}`);
          });
        }
        selectorsArr = reFinalSelectors; 
      }
```

I don't even know where to begin to do this more efficiently as I am just starting to learn how to use array functions and don't have too good of a grasp of the more advanced ones like `Array.reduce()`. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your code actually produce the correct results?

Comment: @jarmod - yes it does

Comment: Example: ``items.store.flatMap(s => items.level.map(l => `.${s}.${l}`))``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the store and city arrays are treated identically for the purposes of the algorithm, so you can put them together. Then all you need to do is match each of those with each `level` - an easy two-dimensional iteration.

The only complication is that if there isn't anything in `level`, to push only the prefix (store/city) instead of iterating over the `level`.

```js
const items = {
  store: [
    'north',
    'evans',
    'dodge'
  ],
  city: [
    'boston',
    'miami',
  ],
  level: [
    'gold',
    'silver'
  ]
};

const { level } = items;
const resultArr = [];
for (const prefix of items.store.concat(items.city)) {
  if (level.length) {
    for (const suffix of level) {
      resultArr.push(`.${prefix}.${suffix}`);
    }
  } else {
    resultArr.push(`.${prefix}`);
  }
}
console.log(resultArr.join(','));
```

Comment: Awesome!! My mind needs a little help getting to that level of thinking at times. This answer is EXTREMELY helpful to me. Thanks!!